# My dropdown disappear when I hover on my button

Tags: html, css

if I hover on my button the dropdown disappear. can some help me?
now it disappear when I hover on my button.
does anyone know how to help this problem out?
I don't used javascript on this dropdown menu.
i'm learning so please help me
i'm using this for my website
I do not know how to add more text at this because it won't post
I am from a country whats not speaking englis so do not bully me for bad englis
please help me

```
   <nav>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a><img class="profile" src="profile.png" href="index.html"/></a>
          <button><a href="#" class="home">Nieuws</a></button>
          <div class="projects">
            <button>Koers<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="nieuws.html">Weather App</a></li>
              <li><a  class="menulink"  href="#">Music App</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">React App</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Youtube App</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="products">
            <button>Kopen/Verkopen<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Cloud Service</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Music Streaming</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Consulting Help</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="Contact">
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

css:

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(139, 62, 85);
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  }
  a,
  button {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }


.profile {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: hotpink;
    margin-left: -10px;
   
}
.header{ 
    background-color: hotpink;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
  
}
.Contact{
    list-style:none;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
  .dropdown {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .projects,
  .products {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .projects ul,
  .products ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;

  }
  .projects li,
  .products li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color:white;
  }
  
  .projects li:hover,
  .products li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(197, 173, 181);
   
   
  }
 
  .projects a,
  .products a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
 
  
  .dropdown button,
  .home {
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
  }
  
  .projects button:hover + ul ,
  .products button:hover + ul{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    
  }
.projects button ul{
  display: block;
}



  i{
    margin-left: 10px;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the :hover pseudo element into the parent element instead of the button.

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(139, 62, 85);
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  }
  a,
  button {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }


.profile {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: hotpink;
    margin-left: -10px;
   
}
.header{ 
    background-color: hotpink;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
  
}
.Contact{
    list-style:none;
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
  .dropdown {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .projects,
  .products {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .projects ul,
  .products ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    left: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;

  }
  .projects li,
  .products li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color:white;
  }
  
  .projects li:hover,
  .products li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(197, 173, 181);
   
   
  }
 
  .projects a,
  .products a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
 
  
  .dropdown button,
  .home {
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
  }
  
  .projects:hover ul ,
  .products:hover ul{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    
  }
.projects button ul{
  display: block;
}



  i{
    margin-left: 10px;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a><img class="profile" src="profile.png" href="index.html"/></a>
          <button><a href="#" class="home">Nieuws</a></button>
          <div class="projects">
            <button>Koers<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="nieuws.html">Weather App</a></li>
              <li><a  class="menulink"  href="#">Music App</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">React App</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Youtube App</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="products">
            <button>Kopen/Verkopen<i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Cloud Service</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Music Streaming</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Consulting Help</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="Contact">
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```